# Joomla 3.1 Front end editing - Deleting and article

Tags: joomla

I have set up user group called "Article Editor" with a parent of Administrator. Within that group I have a user of "Agent" and assigned them to the "Article Editor" User group.

I have a blog page in which when they are logged in they can create an article (only with a particular category called blog) and they can edit all articles, however, I cannot get any option anywhere to enable them to delete any article they have created within the "blog" category. I have gone into the article manage and made sure the permissions are set to enable Edit, Delete and Create.

Any ideas how I allow the user to log into the front end and have the option to delete? Ive tried everything I can think of an am going around in circles now.

Answer (score 2):

The Delete permission should be given only to trusted administrators (with intended access to the back-end) and can be performed in the back-end.
From your description, you don't want this group of users to have access in the back-end and even more have delete permissions, as these users if they log-in to the backend they will be able to delete many things.
These users should be able to edit state (publish/unpublish) their own articles.
So, concluding:
Give this group only front-end access, with permissions similar to the author (core joomla group) with the addition of edit state.
So they will be able to create and publish/unpublish (**addition- or trashing) their articles.

[image: publishing options in front-end article editing]

Comment: So there is no way to delete an article from the front end? I dont mind them having back end access, Its just more difficult to train the users to go to the back end and do whats needed without giving them the temptation to start fiddling with modules - unless there is a way to only let them access back end without being able to see/touch any modules or anythign that can "break" the sites

Comment: To clarify it: What exactly you mean with delete ?  Deleting is to empty the trash. Your users will be able to set their articles status as trashed but they won't be able to Empty the trash.

Comment: By delete I mean remove from the page so that the article is no longer visible to viewers of the site. I dont need them to be able to empty the trash.

Comment: with the edit state permission your users will be able to accomplish this. They will only have to set the article status to unpublished or trashed. For the back-end question.. the answer is yes.. you could create a custom back-end for these users with restricted access... but this would involve extra work and maybe some 3rd party extensions. Also for front-end article management there are some extensions you might want to look at: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-submission

Comment: I must be missing a button or something as when I click edit, the JCE editor comes up, there is an option to save or cancel but no option to change the status of the article? is this something I need to set up?

Ive had a look at the extensions but out of the 3 that were for joomla 3.1 I tried one but wasnt sure if it was what I needed (useful article manager)

Comment: ok! make sure you set the permissions as explained before for com_content and the usersgroup in question and that there is no other conflict from the global permissions. Then in the publishing options of the front-end article editing, there should be the status drop-down list. I added a screen shot in the answer above.

Comment: Oh Im such a dimwit! I couldnt find any default styling for the front end admin form, so ive been copying bits from the prostar theme and because I couldnt see any of the options under publishing as I cant find the right styles, I didnt think it was needed really so I had the publishing tab hidden. Shall go and hunt out the right styling to make the dropdowns etc appear nicely and re-enstate my hidden tab!
Many Thanks for all your time and help. Very much appreciated :)